# unable to call blpapi function (InstrumentsListRequest) using xbbg

Tags: bloomberg

I am trying to call the example of blpapi using xbbg

```
from xbbg.core import conn, process
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import date

def allInstruments():  # Return all govts with the given ticker, matured or not
    req = process.create_request(service='//blp/instruments', request='instrumentListRequest')
    req.set('query', "Dhaka")
    req.set('maxResults', 10)

    def _process_instruments(msg):  # Process the response
            print(msg)
            pass

    conn.send_request(request=req)
    
    processed_elements_list = list(process.rec_events(func=_process_instruments))

    for i in processed_elements_list:
        print(i)

allInstruments()
```

it gives me following error but still i get the result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
h:\tanjin-work\xbbg\Examples.ipynb Cell 45 line 2
     18     for i in processed_elements_list:
     19         print(i)
---> 21 allGovts()

h:\tanjin-work\xbbg\Examples.ipynb Cell 45 line 1
     14 conn.send_request(request=req)
     16 # Process events and get the list of elements
---> 17 processed_elements_list = list(process.rec_events(func=_process_instruments))
     19 # Iterate over the processed elements
     20 for i in processed_elements_list:

File h:\tanjin-work\xbbg\xbbg\core\process.py:197, in rec_events(func, **kwargs)
    195 if ev.eventType() in responses:
    196     for msg in ev:
--> 197         for r in func(msg=msg, **kwargs):
    198             yield r
    199     if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You should ask F1 F1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.